# Tidying a complicated if-else statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm trying to find a tidy way to set a string using an `if else` statement according to a numeric value.

The only complication is that there is a possibility that this value may contain text. So it needs to handle that situation too.

So this is the basic code:

```
                        If cint(QtyShop) > 0 Then
                            msg = "Stock found in this shop"
                        ElseIf cint(QtyAllShops) > 0 Then
                            msg = "Stock found in a different shop"
                        Else
                            msg= "No stock found anywhere"
                        End If
```

The trouble is that if `QtyShop` has a text value rather than numeric it will throw an error. I need it to simply treat this scenario as "false", and continue to the next `elseif`.

At the moment, the only solution I can think of is this ugly monstrosity:

```
                        If IsNumeric(QtyShop) Then
                            If cint(QtyShop) > 0 Then
                                msg = "Stock found in this shop"
                            ElseIf IsNumeric(QtyAllShops) Then
                                If cint(QtyAllShops) > 0 Then
                                    msg = "Stock found in a different shop"
                                Else
                                    msg = "No stock found anywhere"
                                End If
                            Else
                                msg = "No stock found anywhere"
                            End If
                        Else
                            If IsNumeric(QtyAllShops) Then
                                If cint(QtyAllShops) > 0 Then
                                    msg = "Stock found in a different shop"
                                Else
                                    msg = "No stock found anywhere"
                                End If
                            Else
                                msg = "No stock found anywhere"
                            End If
                        End If
```

It makes me feel very sad when I look at it. :- ( Please can someone make it go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate the handling of business logic (“*what* is the quantity?”) and validation.

So first test whether the user input is a valid number. Then put that number into a *numeric* variable – **don’t** handle `String` variables as if they were numbers.

You can make this much easier by enabling `Option Strict`. This will cause the compiler to report errors in your code because you are treating strings as numbers.

Finally, consider early return: return the result as soon as it’s found. This way you can avoid deeply nested statements:

```
' Input validation ….

If QtyShop > 0 Then Return "Stock found in this shop"

If QtyAllShops > 0 Then Return "Stock found in a different shop"

Return "No stock found anywhere"
```

Comment: I can see what you're saying. And ordinarily this is how I would handle it. The difference is that it isn't actually a user-input. It is a value taken from an XML string. So, whatever else I do, the number has to come from a string at some stage.

Comment: @Urbycoz The important point is that the data comes from “somewhere else”. The data flow for external data is always more or less the same: *first* parse and validate the data, *then* operate with the data.

Comment: Your final idea is helpful though. That's the kind of thing I'm after. Thanks!